# Automatic window resizing

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to write a simple function in vim that if a buffer has a small number of lines, after special key-pressing the window fit the whole buffer. Here what I think

```
" get total lines of the current buffer
function! <SID>TotalLines() 
    let n = 0
    for line in getline(1,'$')
        let n+=1
    endfor
    return n
endfunction

" resize the window
function! <SID>ResizeCurrentWindow()
   if has("gui_running")
        let linesNumber = <SID>TotalLines()
        if linesNumber < (&lines / 2)
          execute ':resize linesNumber'
       endif
   endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <leader>rs :call <SID>ResizeCurrentWindow()<CR>
```

well, actually ResizeCurrentWindow() function doesn't work: I obtain a 1-line-height window. But if I write

```
execute 'echo linesNumber'
```

function works and output the right result. Any suggestion? Is there a fastest solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
execute ':resize ' . linesNumber
```

`linesNumber` is a variable and is substituted for its value in the above line. The `.` is a string concatentation operator, adding the string ':resize' and the value of linesNumber to produce the full command you want to execute.

In your code, `"linesNumber"` is a string literal that is passed directly as the argument to the `resize` command.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a function a while back that I think does what you're looking for:

```
fu! AutoResizeWindow(vert) "{{{
    if a:vert
        let longest = max(map(range(1, line('$')), "virtcol([v:val, '$'])"))
        exec "vertical resize " . (longest+4)
    else
        exec 'resize ' . line('$')
        1
    endif
endfu "}}}
```

I use these mappings to call it:

```
:nmap <silent> <leader>wr :call AutoResizeWindow(1)<cr>
:nmap <silent> <leader>wR :call AutoResizeWindow(0)<cr>
```

For me that's: `,wr` resizes vertically and `,wR` resizes horizontally.

Hope this helps.